# How to replace Pivot Application background from code-behind?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm using custom background image in Pivot (not Panorama) Application:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="My Application">
<controls:Pivot.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Theme1.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</controls:Pivot.Background>
```

It works fine, but I would like to replace the image at run-time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give your `ImageBrush` a name:

```
<ImageBrush x:Name="ibPivot" ImageSource="Theme1.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

Then change the source in the code-behind:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("mySecondImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
ibPivot.ImageSource = bi;
```